# Why is my UIWebView displaying nothing after I pull it onscreen?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview

I have a series of three UIWebViews, arranged side-by-side, each one sized to be full screen.

One of them is 'current', one is 'next', and the last is 'previous'.  I have each one populated with test data currently (aptly named 'test one' 'test two' 'test three').  Long term I'll have more than three items to deal with.

Swipes cause the entire shebang to 'rotate' left or right, displaying the next / previous item in the cycle.  The code for the rotation works, as far as I can tell, correctly.  Current takes on the frame of previous, previous takes on next's frame, and next takes on the frame of current.  I then adjust the pointers so that current is pointed to next (which is now placed as current) and so on.  Sounds more complicated than it really is:

```
//code to animate this process properly ommited
previous.hidden=1
CGrect tempFrame=current.frame;
current.frame=previous.frame;
previous.frame=next.frame;
next.frame=tempFrame;
previous.hidden=0

//Adjust the actual pointers so they accurately describe their current positions
UIWebView *temp=current;
current=previous;
previous=next;
next=current;
```

My only issue is that the web views if you go 2 or more in a given direct slide in 'blank'.  E. G. swipe right and you go from test 1 to test 2.  Swipe right again, and you get a blank screen.  THe frames are all correct, the webview is placed correctly, but it's contents are blank.

Confusing thing is, if you swipe once in the opposite direction, and then back, it displays properly.  (E. g. swipe three right, you have a blank; swipe left then back right, and it displays the 'correct' screen.)

Does anyone have any ideas what could possibly be causing this?  I suspect that once I go to my next step ('real data' where next / previous is loaded with the appropriate item when it's slid in) it'll cause the current issue to vanish, but I want to understand THIS issue.

Edit:

I've managed to trace the issue, partially, to my 'hiding' the panel that should NOT be visible.  Past that, I'm still not sure what is going on.

Comment: I think what your doing is in a simple term, deleting the current webview **and then** redrawing it.

Comment: You are not recreating the web views ? If so, try to skip the animation and see what happens.

Comment: No, I'm not deleting the views, I only reposition them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it's related to hiding the 'unused' view in the shuffle.  Why it works when I move backwards to it I don't know.  By moving the 'unused' view to the very back of the order, everything works right.